# Python Dictionaries starter

Tags: python

Cities={"New York City":30, "Boston":54, "Los Angeles":75, "Orlando":114, "Houston":389, "Miami":200}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a beginner problem, and may be better addressed by going through an online python course.

However, I will give you an answer:

```
#Define your dictionary
Cities={"New York City":30, "Boston":54, "Los Angeles":75, "Orlando":114, "Houston":389, "Miami":200}

#Print the NY number
print(Cities["New York City"])

#Calculate the difference between the LA and Orlando numbers
difference = Cities["Los Angeles"] - Cities["Orlando"]

#Print the previously calculated difference
print(difference)
```